# AWS CodeBuild With the CDK "Error: .git/HEAD does not exist"

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

My desire is to build the CDK Cloud Formation stacks using AWS Code Pipeline, from the CDK library `aws-cdk-lib/pipelines`. When running `cdk ls` in the CLI, everything works as expected. I can successfully deploy the pipeline as well with `cdk deploy`.

**Error Message:**

```
[Container] 2022/12/30 09:18:36 Running command npx cdk synth
Error: .git/HEAD does not exist
    at gitHeadPath (/codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/node_modules/git-branch/index.js:36:11)
    at branch (/codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/node_modules/git-branch/index.js:14:28)
    at /codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/src/context/getContext.ts:11:41
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.getContext (/codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/src/context/getContext.ts:9:12)
    at createStack (/codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/bin/template.ts:9:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/bin/template.ts:18:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/codebuild/output/src224694107/src/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
(node:179) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:179) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:179) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**CDK Pipeline Code:**

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-pipeline-${appName}`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-pipeline-${appName}`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment),
    installCommands: ["npm uninstall -g aws-cdk", "npm i -g npm@latest", "npm install -g aws-cdk"],
    commands: ["cd backend", "npm ci", "npm run build", "npx cdk synth"],
    primaryOutputDirectory: "backend/cdk.out",
  }),
});
```

**getContext Function:**

```
export const getContext = (app: App): Promise<CDKContext> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const currentBranch = await gitBranch();
            const environment = app.node.tryGetContext("environments").find((e: any) => e.branchName === currentBranch);
            const globals = app.node.tryGetContext("globals");
            return resolve({...globals, ...environment});
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error("error", error);
            return reject();
        }
    })
}
```

**Package.json dependencies:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha": "^2.55.1-alpha.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.58.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1278.0",
    "constructs": "^10.1.204",
    "git-branch": "^2.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code Build has two options for cloning repositories:**

1. **CodePipeline Default** - *"AWS CodePipeline uses the default zip format for artifacts in the pipeline. Does not include git metadata about the repository"*
2. **Full Clone** - "AWS CodePipeline passes metadata about the repository that allows subsequent actions to do a full git clone. Only supported for AWS CodeBuild actions."

*Quotes taken from the console.*

**Therefore**, the pipeline definition needed to add a Code Commit source prop to tell the CDK to do a full clone. [CDK Docs for options here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeCommitSourceOptions.html)

**Updating the `input`:**

```
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment, {
      codeBuildCloneOutput: true
    })
```

`codeBuildCloneOutput` - *"If this is set, the next CodeBuild job clones the repository (instead of CodePipeline downloading the files)."* This allows for a full clone of the repository, and will remove the error.

**CDK Permissions Update:**

This image shows now the CodeBuild can do a `GitPull`:

[image: CDK Permission Changes]

Comment: Whilst this solved the error, and thus answered the question, obtaining context in Code Build does not include the `branchName` and `environment` key/value pairs, unlike local. These were needed for dynamically naming stacks. E.g. `${environment}-pipeline-${appName}`

Comment: What do you mean by "context"? How are these variables fetched on the local machine?

Comment: They use the git-branch library to look at the branch, and match it to an environment variable stored in the cdk.json

Comment: If you're talking about CDK context variables, then they are definitely available to CodeBuild - maybe you forgot to commit `cdk.context.json`?

Comment: Got a link? I don't know anything about this. Also, please write an answer if you think it is suitable for this question.

Comment: This answer answers the question - I'm addressing your comment. The fact that CodeBuild doesn't see the same CDK context as during local synth is an unrelated issue. I believe this answer should be accepted.